# SQL Timeline overlapping

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone please help me achieving the following :
Table 1 :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLXYB.png)

Table 2 :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMdQD.png)

Expected result :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWJP0.png)

Comment: Please update the question to include text rather than images.  It makes it hard to parse when you have to click on individual images.  You also haven't shared the query you are running.

Comment: Also show us your current SQL attempt.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options could be to Left Join your tables and to use some analytic functions, case expressions and Nvl() function to handle all that should be handled:

```sql
WITH      --  S a m p l e   D a t a
    t1 (P_ID, BID, P_VALID_FROM, P_VALID_TO, P_CURRENT_FLAG) AS
        (   Select 1, '27', To_Date('01.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), To_Date('01.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  0 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, '28', To_Date('02.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), To_Date('02.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  0 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, '27', To_Date('03.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), To_Date('31.12.2099', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  1 From Dual          
        ),
    t2 (P_ID, F_VALID_FROM, F_VALID_TO, F_CURRENT_FLAG) AS
        (   Select 1, To_Date('03.01.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), To_Date('19.04.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  0 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, To_Date('20.04.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), To_Date('04.07.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  0 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, To_Date('05.07.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), To_Date('03.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  0 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, To_Date('04.08.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), To_Date('31.12.2099', 'dd.mm.yyyy'),  1 From Dual 
        )
--
--  M a i n   S Q L
Select    t2.P_ID, 
          Nvl(t1.BID, LAG(t1.BID) OVER(Order By t2.P_ID, t2.F_VALID_FROM)) "BID",   -- LAG() analytic function to handle last row null value
          Nvl(t1.P_VALID_FROM, t2.F_VALID_FROM) "P_VALID_FROM", 
          Case  When      -- LEAD() analytic function to handle two last rows having same value (31.12.2099)
                    LEAD(t2.F_VALID_to) OVER(Order By t2.P_ID, t2.F_VALID_FROM) = Max(t2.F_VALID_TO) OVER(Partition By t2.P_ID) 
                Then t1.P_VALID_FROM
          Else Nvl(t1.P_VALID_TO, t2.F_VALID_TO)
          End "P_VALID_TO", 
          t2.F_CURRENT_FLAG "P_CURRENT_FLAG"
From      t2
Left Join t1 ON(t1.P_ID = t2.P_ID And t1.P_VALID_FROM Between t2.F_VALID_FROM And t2.F_VALID_TO)
Order By  t2.P_ID, t2.F_VALID_FROM, t1.P_VALID_FROM
--
--  R e s u l t
--  P_ID  BID   P_VALID_FROM  P_VALID_TO  P_CURRENT_FLAG
--  ----  ----  ------------  ----------  --------------
--     1  Null  03.01.2023    19.04.2023               0
--     1  Null  20.04.2023    04.07.2023               0
--     1  27    01.08.2023    01.08.2023               0
--     1  28    02.08.2023    02.08.2023               0
--     1  27    03.08.2023    03.08.2023               0
--     1  27    04.08.2023    31.12.2099               1
```